# odbc importer plsqldeveloper not exists excel files

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I'm using PL/SQL Developer version: 10.0.2, Microsoft Official 2016. 
I have a problem with it when I import data from file excel. The problem is: On Dropdwonlist User / System Dms, I don't see value "Excel Files". Se image below

[image]

How can I do import data from Excel in this case?